# How can I set `less` or `more` max lines (scrollable height) limit/boundary in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, less, ps1, more

(Sorry for the title. Any suggestions?)

I've set my commandline PS1 to cover 3 lines:

1. white space
2. user, server and pwd
3. `$` or `#` to input

I think `less` (or `more`?) is configured to break after `window's height - 1`, because when I do a `$ git log`, the first two lines are invisible at the top of the window and the rest is scrollable.

I'm not sure who handles this scrolling and its configuration, but I assume GIT uses `less`/`more`.

Where can I configure that my scrollable window is `window height - 3` lines and not `window height - 1`?

**More info:**

- If I `cat lines.txt | less` with a 23 line file, it shows the entire file and no scrolling.
- If I do the same with a 24 line file, it doesn't show line 1 (and no scrolling).
- With 25 lines: doesn't show lines 1 and 2 (and no scrolling).
- With 26 lines: shows line 1 and scrolling!

The `less` breakpoint is at the wrong height...

Comment: What keeps your prompt at the bottom of your screen while less and more are running? o.O My `screen` session has a statusline forced at the bottom, but it also shrinks the reported window size by 1 so that applications don't have this issue.

Comment: I think it only happens if there aren't enough lines to go to scroll mode (`window height - 1`), but there are enough for some to be invisible (`window height - 3`, since my PS1 is 3 high). (I can't reproduce it now, because I've just pushed which clears the log =))

Comment: Yeah that's it. If I cat+less a file with 26 lines, it shows line 1 at the top and line 25 and `:` at the bottom. If I do the same for a 24 line file it shows line 2 at the top and no scrolling. (If 25 lines, lines 1 and 2 aren't visible.)

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `echo $LESS` ?

Does it work right if you `LESS="" less /path/to/25line/file.txt` ?

Comment: Output of `$ echo $LESS` is `-FRSX`. No idea what that means.... Scrolling behaviour is the exact same with the `LESS=""`.

Comment: The `-F` is your problem. It causes `less` to quit if there's less than one screen of text, but that expects a 1-line prompt. I don't think there's a way to redefine what 'one screen' is, but you can `export LESS="-RSX"` to fix the behavior. Stick it somewhere like your `.profile` or similar to make it persist.